# Facing a issue in populating the status using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database

I am trying to populate the error to the user using ajax, values are saving in a database properly in every query but when trying to show the same in the front end it is not reflecting the same to the end-user.I wanted to populate the status to the end-user using ajax.

Here is my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({ 
url:"controller/client-registration-Controller.php",
                   type:'POST',
  contentType:false,            
  data:data,
   dataType : 'json',
   cache: false,
  processData:false,
     beforeSend: function(){
                $('#insert').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
            }, 
            success: function(strMessage) {

                   $responseText=JSON.parse(strMessage);
                    if($responseText.status=='OK')
             {
              toastr.success(' Registered Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

                //clear all fields
                $('#fupForm').trigger("reset");
             }

                   else if($responseText.status=='ERR'){


                      toastr.error('You Got Error', 'Something  Went Wrong!', {timeOut: 5000}); 


                   } 
                   }


        });

}
        });

 });

  </script>
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $response['status'] = 'ERR';
    $response['message'] = "Mobile is already exist";

    return json_encode($response);
    $res = " Mobile is already exist";

    echo json_encode($res);
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $response['status'] = 'ERR';
    $response['message'] = "Email  is already exist";

    return json_encode($response);

    $res = "Email  is already exist";

    echo json_encode($res);
} elseif (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $response['status'] = 'ERR';
    $response['message'] = "Something Went Wrong";

    return json_encode($response);
    $res = "Something went wrong";

    echo json_encode($res);
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $response['status'] = 'OK';
    $response['message'] = 'Inserted successfully';

    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
    //  $error="Registered Successfully";
    // echo json_encode($error);
}

}
}}
```

I want to populate the status in the front end

Comment: can you console.log($responseText); under success function. Let me know what is in your console.

Comment: I got nothing there as such nothing is printed  This error is there "VM4219:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (register.php:86)
    at i (VM4183 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM4183 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (VM4183 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM4183 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
success

Comment: When posting your code for someone else to read, please format & indent it properly.

Comment: Based on what you described above somehow what your server is returning is not valid json string and JSON.parse is failing. Console.log(strMessage) and see what you are getting and ensure it is valid JSON.